# axiost get method to fetch database records that is another computer

Tags: database, dbconnection

I want to get the records of Database of another computer using axios get method and display them in my webpage using react. I am new to react and i can't find any solution .

I tried assigning the url to a varaible and call them in an object but i am getting my webpage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.